# Stream a canvas session sending chunks to host server WHILE the session is going on

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, webrtc, streaming

CONTEXT : Record a LONG canvas session.

I CAN DO NOW : using `navigator.mediaDevices` connect a webcam to a canvas, the user hit "take photo" => then that photo is sent to host server to save it.

WHAT I WANT : "record" a longer session where in the HTML there is sliders to add some html effects.... and that long session be recorded to saved it in the host server WHILE the session is being done (sending smaller chunks instead of waiting the session to finish).

PRECISION : I emphasize on WHILE because when I search about it I find stuff about recording a session (canvas) then (ONLY when the user hit stop, it can be sent to the host server.....)

it's ok for small sessions (1 min, 2 min), but what about 1 hour, 2 hours, etc ????

I would like : that when the user begins the session (hit start), then it starts to live send chunks **while** the session is still going on.

is it possible ?

is there a javascript library that could give me a head start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `MediaRecorder` is what you're looking for. It's meant to record and encode audio/video content.

You could either use the `timeslice` parameter when calling `start()` or call `requestData()` manually to trigger `dataavailable` events which will emit what has been recorded so far (since the last `dataavailable` event).

```
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(YOUR_STREAM);

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = ({ data }) => {
    // The data property should be a Blob with encoded media.
};

// This will trigger a dataavailable event every second.
mediaRecorder.start(1000);

// This will trigger a single dataavailable event.
mediaRecorder.requestData();
```

Comment: thanks, I'll check this out...

Comment: Your answer inspired me to do some research and concoct this... see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821620/javascript-mediarecorder-dataavailable-empty-data-size-0-only-in-safari-works

Comment: Maybe it's worth to file a bug on Safari's bug tracker. Sadly reporting bugs for Safari is oftentimes a frustrating experience.

Comment: I had this problem with sending a photo from safari via `canvas.toDataURL` .... I fixed it by changing the format to `canvas.toDataURL("image/webp",0.8);` and I think that safari generates LARGE media files..... I'm working on a .slice method, see it here https://www.stubfees.com/templates/tests_ubox_slice/slice.html you can check the source code, I'll try to apply .slice on the mediarecorder...

Comment: I figured it out ;) I created a github for the full solution https://github.com/jintor/stream_mediarecorder/tree/main ::==>> the problem with safari was the rapid trigger of fetch (with combination of async await....) because safari generates BIG media files, it cannot keep up and javascript clogs. so my solution was to use indexedDB as a BUFFER.... `mediaRecorder.start(3000);` the function save the chunk as unit8 array inside a row in indexedDB, then I create a stack or waiting list, so on 1 ajax at the time, see the recorder.js I added in my github repo....

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to make it work. Thanks for sharing your solution.