# javascript mediarecorder dataavailable empty data (size 0) only in safari [works ok in chrome and firefox]

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

The question is about mediaRecorder and event.data 0 size in safari but not in chrome or firefox.

I doing a simple navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to preview it in a video tag. Then with mediarecorder I send data to the server => ALL is working in chrome AND firefox.

But in safari when I console.log(event.data.size) it's always 0 on in safari.

Is it because of the codec or what could a way to work with the data ?

********** ***ALL THE CODE HERE IS WORKING 100% on chrome and firfox***, but NOT in safari

HTML

```
<button id="record" onclick="startRecording();" >start</button>
<video id="gum" autoplay loop playsinline="true" ></video>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let order = 0;
var mediaRecorder;
var sourceBuffer;
var gumVideo = document.querySelector("video#gum");
var constraints = {  audio: true, video: true };

// DEFAULT VP8 AND TEST BROWSER CODEC
stubstream_codec = "video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus";
if ( MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("video/mp4;codecs=h264") === true ) { stubstream_codec = "video/mp4;codecs=h264"; }
if ( MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("video/mp4;codecs=avc1") === true ) { stubstream_codec = "video/mp4;codecs=avc1"; }
if ( MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("video/webm;codecs=av1,opus") === true ) { stubstream_codec = "video/webm;codecs=av1,opus"; }
if ( MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("video/webm;codecs=avc1,opus") === true ) { stubstream_codec = "video/webm;codecs=avc1,opus"; }
if ( MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus") === true ) { stubstream_codec = "video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus"; }
console.log(stubstream_codec);

// GET CAMERA
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( constraints ).then( successCallback, errorCallback );

// SEND STREAM TO VIDEO TAG
function successCallback(stream) { console.log("stream ok", stream); window.stream = stream; gumVideo.srcObject = stream; }

function errorCallback(error) { console.log(error); }

// SEND TO SERVER
function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  console.log(event);  console.log(event.data);
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data); 
    reader.onloadend = async function(event) {
        let arrayBuffer = reader.result; let uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        let response = await fetch("/receiver.php", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ chunk: uint8View, order: order, snowi: "test" }) });
        order += 1;
    }
  }
}

function startRecording() {
  var options = {mimeType: stubstream_codec, bitsPerSecond: 100000};
  try { mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options); } 
  catch (e0) { console.log("Unable to create MediaRecorder with codec"); return false; }
  
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(3000); 
  console.log("MediaRecorder started");  
}

function stopRecording() { mediaRecorder.stop(); }
```

PHP

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
$chunk = $request['chunk'] ?? '';
$order = $request['order'] ?? '';
$snowi = $request['snowi'] ?? '';
$instream_path = 'path_to_save/';
$filePath = $instream_path.$snowi.'.webm';

// ARRAY TO BINARY FORMAT
$binarydata = pack("C*", ...$chunk);

// APPEND RECEIVED CHUNKS TO MAKE 1 PLAYABLE .WEBM ;)
$out = fopen("{$filePath}", $order == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
if ($out) { fwrite($out, $binarydata); fclose($out); }
```

CONSOLE LOG IN CHROME

```
object=> Blob {size: 140261, type: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'}
```

CONSOLE LOG ON SAFARI

```
[Log] object=> – BlobEvent {isTrusted: true, data: Blob, timecode: 0, …} (recookies.js, line 7)
BlobEvent {isTrusted: true, data: Blob, timecode: 0, type: "dataavailable", target: MediaRecorder, …}

[Log] object=> – Blob {size: 0, type: "", slice: function, …} (recookies.js, line 7)
Blob {size: 0, type: "", slice: function, stream: function, text: function, …}
Blobsize: 0type: ""
Blob Prototypearray
Buffer()constructor: function()sizeslice([start], [end], [contentType])
stream()text()typeSymbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"Object Prototype
```

** for stream codec I tried other values, but I always get 0 sized data (on in safari), why ?

---------- EDIT 1 ---------------

When I change to `new MediaRecorder(window.stream);`  without specifying the codec => it works but ONLY for the first chunk (3 seconds) it does send the other after that :(

Comment: Get anywhere with this? Safari 15.4's blobs seem to have zero size.

Comment: I was able to do a "work around".... see https://github.com/jintor/stream_mediarecorder for the full code. I use indexeddb as a buffer

Comment: I have the same issue.  The problem is in function `handleDataAvailable`, the event.data seem to have zero size.

Comment: @KamanWu have you tested my full solution https://github.com/jintor/stream_mediarecorder/blob/main/recorder.js it too big to put in a simple answer. in short, it needs to be converted in a uint8array => then saved in indexedDB => then with javascript a queu + ajax to upload little by little.... ****** please note that some safari don't support that (safari 14 and +) see https://caniuse.com/?search=MediaRecorder