# getUserMedia mediaRecorder how to convert event.data from safari

Tags: javascript, safari, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder, webcam-capture

This question is about **event.data** returned by SAFARI

CONTEXT : something like this tutorial https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api/

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( {  audio: true, video: true } ).then( successCallback, errorCallback );

function successCallback(stream) { window.stream = stream; gumVideo.srcObject = stream; }

function handleDataAvailable(event) { console.log(event.data); ...code to send to server... }

function startRecording() {
  try { mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream); } catch (e0) { return false; }
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable; mediaRecorder.start(3000); 
}
```

IN SAFARI THE LOG
Blob {size: 0, type: "", slice: function, stream: function, text: function, …}Blob

IN CHROME THE LOG
data: Blob {size: 11985, type: 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus'}

so WHY event.data in safari is EMPTY ?????

Is there a way to convert to string to base64 ?

Comment: All or only the first one? What version of Safari? What OS?

Comment: @Kaiido each one separately see this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821620/javascript-mediarecorder-dataavailable-empty-data-size-0-only-in-safari-works ===>>> it works in chrome and safari ==>> each data.event contains data => I send to server individually and reconstruct at server side => it's all working. the issue I have to wall safari (i could test 14 and +) is that the @!#!@#!@ event.data contains NOT DATA at all :( so where is the pixel stored?

Comment: @Kaiido you can test from your side with chrome, firefox and safari https://www.stubfees.com/templates/tests/streamrtc2.php to see what I'm talking about

Comment: Can't repro, for me only the first slice is empty (which is to be expected), the other ones all have data. (your link doesn't show me anything). And how is this question different than your previous one then?

Comment: @Kaiido I re-updated the link, you can test it now to see the log

Comment: Can't repro on my Safari 15.4 all slices have data for me.

Comment: @Kaiido strange, from my end with safari 15.4 https://stub3fs.s3.filebase.com/jmedia/ownmulti/15550813029132/16642135955346/16642135955346.webp

Comment: @Kaiido when I test i on my iphone, it sends ONLY the first blob, after it suddenly reloads the page and don't continue :(

Comment: Mobile (iPhone  iPad) Safari and Mac Safari are different beasts, at least as far as gUM is concerned. You may want to [edit] your question to be clear about which one you work with. If it's mobile you may want to rig up the debugging connection where you can see the mobile console inside Mac Safari. That will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @O.Jones I think the safari bug is due to a large file generated (compared to vp9 or vp8...) I'll continue to do some tests and reply with a workable answer... I made a ajax uploader with file slicing before, I'll concoct something for this

Comment: @O.Jones I found it... I can use indexeddb as a buffer : each blob are converted in uint8 => then saved in indexeddb => ajax to send like a queue.... see the full code here https://github.com/jintor/stream_mediarecorder